# triple integral and limits

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

$$\iiint\limits_H (x^2+y^2) \, dx \, dy \, dz \\
H=\{(x,y,z) \in R^3: 1 \le x^2+y^2+z^2 \le9, z \le 0 \}$$

I'm using Spherical coordinate system:
$$x=r\cos \theta \cos\phi $$
$$y=r\cos \theta \sin\phi $$
$$z=r\sin \theta  $$

and $r \in (1,3), \theta \in (0,2 \pi)$ but I don't know how to find set for $\phi$?
Could anyone explain me in an easy way how to find $\phi$ [in this case and in general]?

Comment: Hint: $z \leq 0$ tells you what you need for this case.

Comment: $\phi \in [ \pi, 2 \pi ]$ ??

Comment: It does span a range of $\pi$ radians, but it's not from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ if $\phi = 0$ is defined as pointing straight up in the $z$ direction.

Comment: Do you have your coordinates right? I think you may have your $\cos \theta$s swapped for $\sin \theta$ and vice versa.

Comment: Actually, my comment above is wrong -- I forgot $\phi \in (0, \pi)$ instead of $\phi \in (0, 2\pi)$. You want half the range of $\phi$ so the range is $\pi/2$.

Comment: Heyy so what is the answer? If I have $rsin \phi \le 0$ then $sin \phi \le 0$ so $\phi \in [ \pi, 2 \pi ]$ is it something I could also take into consideration?

Comment: Notation varies from one text to another, but usually $x=r\cos\theta=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta$, $z=\rho\cos\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: should be between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$  for a if you redefine $$z=r \cos(a),x=r \sin(a)\cos(b), y=r \sin(a) \sin(b)$$ and b between 0 2π and r between 1 and 3

Notice the region is below or equal to the plane $z=0$ and the 2 spheres

Answer (score 0):

You are integrating in a sphereically symmetric region (from the radius 1 sphere out to the radius 3 sphere). So in these co-ordinates you want $\theta \in \{0,\pi\} $ and $ \phi \in \{0,2\pi\}$. Theta ($\theta$) is the polar angle going from the "north pole" down to the "south pole" -- the lattitude of sorts (only $\pi$ radians). Phi ($\phi$) is the azimuthal angle or the "longitude". That one goes a full circle around the region ($2 \pi$ radians).

*Added*: Oops I overlooked that $z\le 0$. OK so Longitudinaly you are still good but now you integrate $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi /2$. The angle $\theta = \pi/2$ represents the equator of your region or $z = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $z\leq 0$ then $\phi$ should be

> $$  \pi/2\leq \phi \leq \pi.  $$

Comment: $sin \phi \le 0$ why this?

Comment: @keri: Do you know what's $\phi$?

Comment: yes, this is angle. z<0 so we take lower half of sphere. Both of the quadrants are symmetric so we can take only one of it, so I guess the answer is $ [\pi, 3 \pi /2]$ or $[3 \pi/2 ; 2 \pi ]$
Am I wrong?

Comment: @keri: I already gave ypu $\phi$ which you need. You should know that $\phi$ is allowed to varies in the interval $[0,\pi]$. Check the derivation of spherical coordinates.